# How to create foreign key in Hibernate on Integer column

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have an entity in Java and I would like Hibernate to create a foreign key from an Integer field (since I don't have an object reference):

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {

    ...
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer generatedBy;
    ...
```

I think I'd like to do something like this with an attribute:

```
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_Invoice_GeneratedBy", references="UserTable.UserId")
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer generatedBy;
```

What is the best way to achieve this?  I would preferably not have to maintain these relationships in a separate file (if possible).

Comment: Just a question: What are the reasons you don't have a reference to the user?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for it. Such as 1) performance reasons (I don't want to "suck" up too much information) or 2) it's a table in the database that is not represented by an entity in my system (or I don't have any control over it)... but for me it's mostly nr. 1

Comment: 1.) Lazy loading
2.) If there's no entity representation, why do you need hibernate to know about the foreign key constraint?

Comment: 1) Lazy loading makes it even slower.  Thing is I need to return these entities over web service boundaries which causes the whole object hierarchy to materialize. This has cause significant performance problems.   2) I want to maintain database integrity, I don't really need it for Hibernate as such but do find it the best location to store it close to the class/field definitions.

Comment: 1) Well, if you transfer the entities over web services I'd higly recommend the data transfer object pattern and lazy loading would not be a problem anymore (even if you'd transfer the detached entity, you would not need to initialize all non-loaded associations, accessing them would then "just" cause an exception).
2) You can declare the foreign key constraint in the database directly. I'd also not recommend relying on Hibernate to maintain the database structure. If it's just information for the programmer, add a comment.

Comment: 1) Feels like the DTO pattern is a bit of an overkill (and there are some mixed opinions on them as can be read here on SO).  2) I don't really have a problem devising a process for maintaining this information. The fact is that declaring this information in the source file is the most natural place locality-wise to store that information since other foreign keys are declared there (via object references), check constraints, indexes. I want the same to apply to foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a solution to this, thus accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, but it is not very nice...

You can have your integer attribute, AND an object attribute mapped this way:

```
@Column(ame = "GENERATED_BY", nullable = true)
private Integer generatedBy;

@ForeignKey(name="FK_Invoice_GeneratedBy")
@JoinColumn(name = "GENERATED_BY", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
private User generatedByUser;
```

You may keep no external access to your generatedByUser field, it will only show hibernate that there is a relationship. You can set the Integer field at will, when you load this object from DB later you'll have your user reference.

Again, not very pretty, but can be useful sometimes.

Comment: I'd actually prefer that the User object wouldn't get loaded.  I tried what you recommended but got dubious output for the DDL: ..., generatedBy integer, generatedByUser varchar(255) for bit data,